# Acumatica Mobile App - Inventory Allocation Details

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have added the Inventory Allocation Details (IN402000) to Mobile Acumatica

**ISSUE 1**

When Opening the Inventory Allocation Detail (IN402000) screen on the mobile app, I would like the screen to open with the fields showing but instead an empty block open which I need to click on and then I am redirected to the screen as shown below.

[image]

**ISSUE2**
When selecting Inventory ID or any of the selector fields on the mobile app the details does not populate like it does on Acumatica Web - only the Item Plan tab gets populated with the first item as show on the screenshots. How can I fix the issue in order for the fields to be populated as one of the selectors such as Inventory ID is selected?

**Populated Web version - Item Plan tabs**

[image]

**Web Version 2 - QTY BY PLAN TYPE tab**
[image]

**Mobile Version 1**

[image]

**Mobile Version 2 - Item Plans tab**

[image]

**Mobile Version 3 - QTY BY PLAN TYPE tabs**

[image]

**Code Snippet of the creation of the screen**

```
add screen IN402000 {
  
  add container "Selection"
    {
    


    add layout "layout1" {
    
        layout = "Inline"  
        add field "InventoryID"
  
    }
  
    add layout "layout2" {
 
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Warehouse"
        add field "LotSerialNbr"
    }
    
    add layout "layout3" {
    
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Location"
        add field "BaseUnit"
    
    }

   add group "Header"{
    
        displayName = "Header"
        collapsable = true
        collapsed = false
        add field "OnHand"
        add field "Available"
        add field "AvailableForShipping"
        add field "AvailableForIssue"
        add field "OnLocNotAvailable"
        add field "Expired"
        add field "Label"
        add field "Label2"
    
    }
    
    add group "Details"{
    displayName = "ITEM PLANS"
    collapsable = true
    collapsed = True
    
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#Module"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#AllocationType"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#AllocationDate"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#DocumentType"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#ReferenceNbr"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#Subitem"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#Warehouse"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#Location"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#LotSerialNumber"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#Qty"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#AccountID"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#AccountName"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#LocNotAvailable"
     add field "ItemPlansAllocationDetails#Expired"

    }
  
   add recordAction "Cancel" {
     behavior = Cancel
    }

   add recordAction "ViewDocument" {
      syncLongOperation = true
      behavior = void
      redirect = true
    }

    
   add recordAction "ViewSummary" {
      syncLongOperation = true
      behavior = void
      redirect = true
    }
    

   add group "QtyByPlanTypeAddition"{
       displayName = "QTY BY PLAN TYPE - ADDITION"
       collapsable = true
       collapsed = True
        
        add field"QtyByPlanTypeAddition#PlanType"
        add field"QtyByPlanTypeAddition#Quantity"
        add field"QtyByPlanTypeAddition#Included"
        
    
    
    }
    

    
   add group "QtyByPlanTypeDeduction"{
     displayName = "QTY BY PLAN TYPE - DEDUCTION"
     collapsable = true
     collapsed = True
    
    add field"QtyByPlanTypeDeduction#PlanType"
    add field"QtyByPlanTypeDeduction#Quantity"
    add field"QtyByPlanTypeDeduction#Included"
    
    
    
    }
    
    }
    
    
}
```

**Code snippet of the MENU**

```
update sitemap {
 add item "IN402000"{
    displayName = "Inventory Allocation Details"
    icon = "system://Pen"
    
    
    }
}
```